# What is the proper way to get data from two eloquent relational model in laravel/lumen?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I am trying to build up a relation with some eloquent table and try to make api that actually retrieve data from two relational table. Here a photo to understand.

[image]

Lets consider employees and employee_types for simplify the problem. My migration code looks like

```
        Schema::create('os_employee_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('priority')->default(0);
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And,

```
    Schema::create('os_employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->bigInteger('employee_type')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('employee_type')->references('id')->on('os_employee_types');
    });
```

Here in employee table, employee_type is a foreign key in employee types table that relation with id on employee type table. And my model looks like

```
class OsEmployeeType extends Model
 {
public function OsEmployee()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OsEmployee::class);
}
 }
```

And,

```
 class OsEmployee extends Model
  { 
public function OsEmployeeType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(OsEmployeeType::class);
}    
 }
```

Now the controller looks like

```
   public function check(){
$employee = OsEmployee::with('OsEmployeeType')->get();
return new OsEmployeeMaxCollection($employee);
}
```

I got the response

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Arafat Rahman",
        "employee_type": 2,
        "created_at": "2022-03-01T11:23:05.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-03-01T11:23:05.000000Z",
    }
]
 }
```

This is absolute data from os_employee table. but I want the data with employee type. I want the response like

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Arafat Rahman",
        "employee_type": {
               "id": 2,
                "name": "employee_type 1",
                 "priority": 10,
                  "status": 1
          },
        "created_at": "2022-03-01T11:23:05.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-03-01T11:23:05.000000Z",
       
    }
]
 }
```

Here is the dd($employee)

[image]

And OsEmployeeMaxCollection looks like

```
class OsEmployeeMaxCollection extends ResourceCollection
   {
/**
 * Transform the resource collection into an array.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
  }
```

What was my mistake or wrong? How can I get data like my description.

Comment: can you dd $employee = OsEmployee::with('OsEmployeeType')->get();
 this ? dd($employee); and check if the relation exists and what is OsEmployeeMaxCollection ? Can you share it aswell

Comment: edited. please check

Comment: There is "relations" key inside this dd it is OsEmployeeType check it plese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function check(){
    
    return OsEmployee::with('OsEmployeeType')->get();
}
```

This should work. If it does not have OsEmployeeType this field should not be empty.

If you want json reponse

```
public function check(){
    
    return OsEmployee::with('OsEmployeeType')->get()->toJson();
}
```

and change your code migration to:

```
   Schema::create('os_employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->bigInteger('employee_type_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('employee_type_id')->references('id')->on('os_employee_types');
    });
```

And your model to:

```
 class OsEmployee extends Model
  { 
public function OsEmployeeType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(OsEmployeeType::class, 'employee_type_id');
}    
 }
```

Comment: it gives same response as well

Comment: No it should not. You dd it and it says #relations: [1]. Under it there should be OsEmployeeType

Comment: check it again please

Comment: Please change your migration too. I changed employee_type_id and check it again

Comment: @arafat rahman If it is working do not forget to upvote and and mark my answer is check. I looked your profile and you never marked your questions' answers as correct.

Comment: But it actually did not work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242522/discussion-between-arafat-rahman-and-gguney).